# Install ConTeXt manually without using first-setup.bat

Tags: installing, context

For some reason or the other, when I try to install ConTeXt on my machine (Windows 7 OS), it gives an error as shown below:

[image]
[image]

So I have tried and tried and tried and tried. You get the point. I was wondering if it is possible to just download the files that it is supposed to download and install manually. I am looking at this [page](http://www.pragma-ade.com/download-1.htm) but don't know if am in the right place. And if so, how can install it manually; that is, in the correct folders?

NOTE: I have read some of the posts here but I have not reached a solution. By the way, it does not download anything.

Comment: May be internet problem. It should work. Check your connectivity and internet speed. What is the speed? Also the servers may be down.

Comment: @HarishKumar The speed? Hmmm honestly I don't know? Where do I look for that? I can't think right now.

Comment: You can use some band width meters. https://www.google.co.in/search?q=bandwidth+meter+online+speed+test&oq=band+width+meter+online&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.12631j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8 and   http://www.speedtest.net/

Comment: @HarishKumar I got this http://www.speedtest.net/result/3174261268.png

Comment: Your speed is good (better than mine `:-)`). Sorry no ideas. May be servers are down.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Set RSYNC_PROXY=<your proxy here> environment variable.

Comment: If you do not want ConTeXt-beta, you can also download ConTeXt using texlive.

Comment: @Aditya Are there tutorials on how to do it? Can you give quick tips on the process to download it using TeXLive? I can possible accept an answer like. If you make it thorough, it would help other users.

Comment: TeXLive is a TeX distribution. You can get it on DVD, see https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-dvd.html or you can download the package and install it, depending on how bad your internet connection is.