# ConTeXt: Install offline version on CentOS 6

Tags: installing, context, linux, centos

## Background

Looking to install ConTeXt on CentOS 6, without an Internet connection.

## Problem

The CentOS 6 server does not have Internet access, but can receive files from a computer on the same local area network.

## Related

There are a number of related issues, inluding:

- [Install ConTeXt manually without using first-setup.bat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150632/2148)
- [Offline Installation: How do I install a full TeX distribution on an offline computer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/105648/2148)
- [How to install ConTeXt on CentOS 7?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/344265/2148)

However, these questions do not address the offline nature specifically for the latest version of ConTeXt available at http://standalone.contextgarden.net/setup/linux-64/.

## Question

Given a machine running Windows (or Cygwin on top of Windows, or Linux, even, as the instructions can likely port), how would you download and install an offline version of ConTeXt on a server running CentOS 6 for all users?

The following steps will not work, but serve as an example of what I'd like to accomplish:

1. On Windows, open Cygwin.
2. Type:

   ```
   mkdir $HOME/context
   cd $HOME/context
   curl --recursive http://standalone.contextgarden.net/setup/linux-64/ .
   ```
3. On Windows, open WinSCP (or file transfer program).
4. Connect to CentOS server.
5. Transfer entire `linux-64` directory.
6. Disconnect WinSCP.
7. On Windows, open Putty (or other remote shell access program).
8. Connect and login to CentOS server.
9. Change to `root` user.
10. Type:

    ```
    mkdir /opt/context
    cd /opt/context
    cp -R /home/user/linux-64  .
    cd linux-64
    ./first-setup.sh
    ```
11. Optionally, disconnect from the server.

At this point, ConTeXt would be installed on CentOS 6 and all users can create PDFs from `.tex` files.

Comment: Just install ConTeXt on another Cent OS 6 machine, compress the entire `/opt/context`, transfer, done.  ConTeXt does not rely on any files outside its tree.

Comment: Then use a virtual machine, e.g. [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)).

Comment: I uploaded the tree I generated from my answer [here](https://transfer.sh/mD5YU/ctx-centos6.tar.gz) (link valid 14 days, SHA1 `6e092fc6b66de7f4f2bbdd1b6c56dbc5abca1b1b`).  However, I urge you to not trust me and rather build the tree yourself using the instructions below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Overview

Since ConTeXt does not rely on any files outside its tree, one solution follows:

1. Install ConTeXt on another Cent OS 6 machine.
2. Archive `/opt/context`.
3. Transfer the archive to the offline machine.
4. Delete and then [regenerate](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone#Moving_the_installation_tree_around) the cache.

---

#### Install ConTeXt via Docker

These instructions describe how to install offline using Docker. If Docker is not available, use another virtualization solution (such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)).

1. Download and [install Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/). See also:

   - https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows
   - https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#download-docker-for-windows
   - https://blog.docker.com/2017/09/preview-linux-containers-on-windows/
2. Make a new directory (I chose `/tmp/centos`) and change into it.

   ```bash
   mkdir -p /tmp/centos
   cd /tmp/centos
   ```
3. Fire up the Docker CentOS 6 container and mount the current directory to `/opt/context`.  The `-it` switch (short for `--interactive --tty`) drops you into an interactive session.

   ```bash
   sudo docker run -v `pwd`:/opt/context -it centos:6 /bin/bash
   ```

   You now have a shell inside the container.

   > 1. To be able to download the necessary files and install ConTeXt, install `rsync` and `wget`.
   >
   >    ```bash
   >    yum install -y rsync wget
   >    ```
   > 2. Install ConTeXt.
   >
   >    ```bash
   >    cd /opt/context
   >    wget http://minimals.contextgarden.net/setup/first-setup.sh
   >    sh ./first-setup.sh --modules=all
   >    ```
   > 3. Log out of the container.
   >
   >    ```bash
   >    exit
   >    ```
4. You should now have a ConTeXt installation in the working directory.  Compress it.

   ```bash
   tar -czvf /tmp/ctx-centos6.tar.gz .
   ```
5. Transfer.
6. Create target directory and extract.

   ```bash
   mkdir /opt/context
   tar -xzvf ctx-centos6.tar.gz -C /opt/context
   ```
7. Use ConTeXt.

   ```bash
   . /opt/context/tex/setuptex
   ```